# System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

If I debug a WPF-application with Catalog.xaml as Content, I can't get the resource stream of it - GetResourceStream returns null:

`var uri = new Uri("/Assembly;component/Catalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

var foo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(uri);`

foo is null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is "Assembly" your assembly name?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for type Content you only need the item name:

```
var uri = new Uri(**"Catalog.xaml"**, UriKind.Relative);
var foo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
```